# Is it possible to get rid of XML/Config class wiring in Spring IOC Container?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, inversion-of-control

I'm learning to use Spring and in particular IOC. I'd like to use annotations to get rid of bean-defining config files and I thought that was what @Autowired annotation was for, but my beans don't seem to instantiate when I'm using it, so I don't know if i'm doing things wrong or if it is just not how it is supposed to work.

web.xml :

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
     version="3.1">

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>org.example.demo.ticket.webapp.rest.SpringConfig</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
    <param-value>org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext</param-value>
</context-param>
</web-app>
```

SpringConfig class :

```
package org.example.demo.ticket.webapp.rest;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan("org.example.demo.ticket")
public class SpringConfig {

}
```

The resource Example that I want to wire and the class in which I want to use it :

```
package org.example.demo.ticket.webapp.rest.resource;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component("exe")
public class Example {

    private String name;

    public Example() {
        name = "Whatever";
    }

}

package org.example.demo.ticket.webapp.rest.resource.projet;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class ProjectResource {

    private Example exe;

    @Autowired
    public void setExe(Example pExe) {
        exe = pExe;
    }
}
```

Now when I instantiate a ProjectResource object, I'd expect it to be equiped with an intantiated exe, but that is not what happens, the exe attribute is always nulll.

Answer (score 0):

You can consider making your application using Spring Boot. It automatically scans for Beans, so you don't have do specify packages. And if you would like to create bean, you can stick with the @Component, @Service or @Controller annotations :)

https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot/